# when the current flow through a resistor, what does it lose?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electric-circuits, electric-current

We all know that in a series circuit, the current is the same for all of the elements.

But when the current flow through a resistor, what does it lose?

The current is the same because it doesn't lose the numbers of charges.
My first thought is since that the flow is caused by potential difference,
and the difference affects the kinetic energy of the charges or how far the charges could flow. Therefore, I thought maybe these charges lose the "velocity".

However, since 
$$
I=\int_AJ\cdot dA
$$
$$
J=nq\textbf{v} 
$$

If the area keeps the same, n and q are fixed, to keep current I is constant, velocity won't change, either.

Then what do the charges lose?
What does the loss of energy really mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The electrons lose electric potential energy.

The electrons are "pushed" through the circuit due the the electric field produced by your power supply (like a battery). As the electrons travel around the circuit they lose potential energy (much like how moving an object downwards on the surface of the earth causes it to lose gravitational potential energy).

The electrons then gain this energy back when they are "inside" the power supply, as the power supply moves the electrons against the electric field, which increases their electric potential energy.

Comment: It depends on what power supply it is. Inside an electrochemical cell
(aka "battery") there are no electrons moving between electrodes.
Charge is transferred by positive and/or negative ions. The former
recombine at the positive electrode with electrons from external
circuit. Negative ions instead lose their excess electron(s) at the
negative electrode, which flow along the external circuit. Energy comes from these processes of ions dissociation and recombination.

Comment: @ElioFabri Yes this is true. I just didn't want to get into the workings of batteries because the OP's question is focused on current through resistors.

Answer (score 0):

The mobile charge leaving the resistor has less potential energy than when entering.

Recall that a resistor with non-zero current through has, by Ohm's law, a non-zero voltage across, i.e., there is a potential difference across the terminals of the resistor.

Thinking in terms of electrons, the electrons exit the resistor terminal that is the more positive.  But, due to the negative electric charge carried by electrons, the potential energy of an electron at the more positive terminal is *less* than the potential energy at the other terminal.

The energy lost is converted to thermal energy in the resistor, i.e., the resistor is heated by the current through.